# Bcrypt error when saving user to mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, bcrypt

at the moment I'm following a tutorial to push myself in the topics node + react.

The link to the repo is https://bitbucket.org/grtn/cloudstruct/src/develop/

When I make a post request to /api/users/register i get the following error in the console and i can't figure out why.

```
/Users/****/Dev/cloudstruct/routes/api/users.js:38
                        if(err) throw err;
                                ^

Error: Illegal arguments: undefined, string
    at _async (/Users/****/Dev/cloudstruct/node_modules/bcryptjs/dist/bcrypt.js:214:46)
    at Object.bcrypt.hash (/Users/****/Dev/cloudstruct/node_modules/bcryptjs/dist/bcrypt.js:220:13)
    at bcrypt.genSalt (/Users/****/Dev/cloudstruct/routes/api/users.js:37:28)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (/Users/****/Dev/cloudstruct/node_modules/bcryptjs/dist/bcrypt.js:153:21)
    at runCallback (timers.js:756:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:717:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:697:5)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

The Usermodel looks like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    avatar:{
        type: String
    },
    date:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);
```

And my routing:

```
const express = require ('express');
const router = express.Router();
const gravatar = require('gravatar');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

// Load User model
const User = require ('../../models/User')

//@route    GET api/users/test
//desc      Tests post route
//@access   Public
router.get('/test', (req, res) => res.json({msg: '<h1>Hello World</h1>'}));

//@route    POST api/users/register
//desc      Register User
//@access   Public
router.post('/register', (req, res) =>{
    User.findOne({ email: req.body.email })
        .then(user => {
            if(user) {
                return res.status(400).json({email: 'Email already exists'});
            } else {
                const avatar = gravatar.url(req.body.email, {
                    s: '200',
                    r: 'pg',
                    d: 'mm'
                });

                const newUser = new User({
                    name: req.body.name,
                    email: req.body.email,
                    avatar: avatar,
                    password: req.body.password
                });

                bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
                    bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
                        if(err) throw err;
                        newUser.password = hash;
                        newUser
                            .save()
                            .then(user => res.json(user))
                            .catch(err => console.log(err));
                    })
                });
            }
        });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your `newUser.password` is undefined. I am afraid that we can access mongoose docs like this. The solution in this case is to use `req.body.password` in .hash()

For reference: If you want to access the key value of a mongoose doc, your have to parse the doc into JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to hash passwords with Mogoose is to use [presave middleware](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre). It will give you a guarantee that user password will always be hashed regardless of the place where you want to create a user record. Also, it's better for architecture: hashing will be made in the data layer instead of routing.

[Here](http://devsmash.com/blog/password-authentication-with-mongoose-and-bcrypt) is a good example. Middleware is described in the step 2.